# The type or namespace name 'ConnectionStringSetting' could not be found

Tags: node.js, .net, azure-functions

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB;
using System.Configuration;


namespace Company.Function
{
    public static class GetResumeCounter
    {
        [FunctionName("GetResumeCounter")]
        public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [CosmosDB(databaseName: "AzureResume", containerName:"Counter", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureResumeConnectionString",Id="1",PartitionKey="1")] Counter counter,
            [CosmosDB(databaseName: "AzureResume", containerName:"Counter", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureResumeConnectionString",Id="1",PartitionKey="1")] out Counter updatedCounter,             
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            updatedCounter = counter;
            updatedCounter.Count += 1;
            
            var jsonToRetun = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(counter);

            return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(jsonToRetun, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
        }
    }
}
```

this is my GetResumeCounter.cs file and whenever i am trying to run func host start its showing me error:

> func host start MSBuild version 17.7.3+8ec440e68 for .NET
> Determining projects to restore...   All projects are up-to-date for
> restore.
> C:\Users\kamle\Desktop\azure-resume\backend\api\GetResumeCounter.cs(19,77):
> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ConnectionStringSetting'
> could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)
> [C:\Users\kamle\Desktop\azure-resume\backend\api\api.csproj]
> C:\Users\kamle\Desktop\azure-resume\backend\api\GetResumeCounter.cs(20,77):
> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ConnectionStringSetting'
> could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)
> [C:\Users\kamle\Desktop\azure-resume\backend\api\api.csproj]
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> C:\Users\kamle\Desktop\azure-resume\backend\api\GetResumeCounter.cs(19,77):
> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ConnectionStringSetting'
> could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)
> [C:\Users\kamle\Desktop\azure-resume\backend\api\api.csproj]
> C:\Users\kamle\Desktop\azure-resume\backend\api\GetResumeCounter.cs(20,77):
> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ConnectionStringSetting'
> could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)
> [C:\Users\kamle\Desktop\azure-resume\backend\api\api.csproj]
> 0 Warning(s)
> 2 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:03.03
>
> Error building project

I checked everything like the version of dotnet and installed NuGet packages too but it's still not working.

Comment: Is this v4 of Azure Functions? Your syntax matches v2

Answer (score 0):

`ConnectionStringSetting` is the name of the Attribute property for the connection string in Functions v2.x. If you are experiencing this error message then it suggests that you are actually coding for the v4.x runtime, in which case the name of the same attribute property is simply: `Connection`

This is covered here: [Azure Cosmos DB output binding for Function: Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#attributes)

```
 [CosmosDB(databaseName: "AzureResume", 
           containerName:"Counter", 
           Connection: "AzureResumeConnectionString",
           Id: "1",
           PartitionKey: "1")] Counter counter,
[CosmosDB(databaseName: "AzureResume", containerName:"Counter", Connection = "AzureResumeConnectionString",Id="1",PartitionKey="1")] out Counter updatedCounter,
```

The other hint to support this is that `ContainerName` is a v4.x property. The similar positional property in v2.x was `CollectionName`.

Comment: thank you for your valuable suggestion, it works